# Does $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||A_n\varphi - A \varphi||_Y = 0$ imply $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||A_n|| = ||A||$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand different modes of convergence in a Banach space.

Suppose we have a sequence of bounded linear operators $A_n:X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, that converge pointwise and in operator norm to an operator $A$, i.e. we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} ||A_n\varphi - A \varphi||_Y = 0, \\
\lim_{n\to \infty} ||A_n - A || = 0.
\end{align}
Can we then say any/all/none of the following:

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = A$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||A_n|| = ||A||$
3. $||\lim_{n\to \infty}  A_n|| = ||A||$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will helps you
$$|\left\| {{A_n}} \right\| - \left\| A \right\|| \leqslant \left\| {{A_n} - A} \right\|$$
For the second question, the norme is a continuous application, so 2 and 3 are both correct.

Comment: Ok I can understand question 2 now thanks! But how do we take the limit outside in question 3 so that we can use the result in question 2? And what about question 1..does this question make sense considering that have not specified any norm function? Do we always have to specify a norm before we can talk about convergence?

Comment: to talk about operator convergence you need a distance (in our case is a norm), without that you can not do anything, concerning your question about the limit outside, I have already answered, the norm is continuous application (you can do this as a little exercise)

Comment: Recall: if $f$ is continous at a poit  $x$ then  for any sequence converge to $x$ we have $$\mathop {lim}\limits_{n \to \infty } f({x_n}) = f(\mathop {lim}\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n})$$.

Comment: ..hmmm I'm not 100% sure. This a norm for the operator instead of the norm for a function. If we write the operator norm as $||A_n|| =  \sup_{||\phi||_X=1}  ||A_n \phi||_Y$, I don't think it is straightforward to bring the limit inside such a norm just with continuity.